# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

all

I try to write this code using JNI, but nothing works. Any suggestion ?

```
extern "C"
{

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloView_drawingBitmap(JNIEnv *env, jfloat width, jfloat height, jobject canvas, jobjectRefType paint);

}

class JniBitmap
{
public:
    uint32_t* _storedBitmapPixels;
    AndroidBitmapInfo _bitmapInfo;
    JniBitmap()
    {
        _storedBitmapPixels = NULL;
    }
};

JniBitmap *jniBitmap = new JniBitmap();

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloView_drawingBitmap(JNIEnv *env, jfloat width, jfloat height, jobject canvas, jobjectRefType paint){

jclass getcanvasClass = env -> FindClass("android/graphics/Canvas");
    jmethodID drawBitmapFunction = env->GetMethodID(getcanvasClass, "drawBitmap", "(Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;FFLandroid/graphics/Paint;)V");

   env-> CallVoidMethod(getcanvasClass, drawBitmapFunction, jniBitmap->_storedBitmapPixels, width, height, paint);


}
```

log:

```
[ 07-23 13:22:44.849 24629:24890 D/         ]
                                                                 ro.exynos.dss isEnabled: 0
07-23 13:22:44.849 24629-24890/com.example.hellojni D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] 

JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, float, float, android.graphics.Paint) on instance of java.lang.Class<android.graphics.Canvas>


07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     in call to CallVoidMethodV
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     from void com.example.hellojni.HelloView.drawingBitmap(float, float, android.graphics.Canvas, android.graphics.Paint)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] "Thread-1691" prio=5 tid=10 Runnable
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c84940 self=0x7faba89a00
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | sysTid=24889 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fabbfd440
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | state=R schedstat=( 57509155 44992191 10 ) utm=5 stm=0 core=4 HZ=100
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | stack=0x7fabafb000-0x7fabafd000 stackSize=1037KB
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #00 pc 000000000048a5b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+200)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #01 pc 0000000000459358  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, BacktraceMap*) const+224)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #02 pc 000000000030d764  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1004)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #03 pc 000000000030e01c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, std::__va_list)+116)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #04 pc 000000000014217c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+144)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #05 pc 0000000000142574  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::CheckMethodAndSig(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+724)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #06 pc 000000000015bc58  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+724)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #07 pc 000000000015def8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+68)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #08 pc 00000000000013a0  /data/app/com.example.hellojni-2/lib/arm64/libJniBitmapOperations.so (_JNIEnv::CallVoidMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+192)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #09 pc 0000000000001238  /data/app/com.example.hellojni-2/lib/arm64/libJniBitmapOperations.so (Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloView_drawingBitmap+200)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #10 pc 0000000000003ae0  /data/app/com.example.hellojni-2/oat/arm64/base.odex (void com.example.hellojni.HelloView.drawingBitmap(float, float, android.graphics.Canvas, android.graphics.Paint)+196)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #11 pc 000000000000397c  /data/app/com.example.hellojni-2/oat/arm64/base.odex (void com.example.hellojni.HelloView.draw()+624)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #12 pc 0000000000003e10  /data/app/com.example.hellojni-2/oat/arm64/base.odex (void com.example.hellojni.HelloView.run()+132)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #13 pc 0000000002f4e654  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (???)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.example.hellojni.HelloView.drawingBitmap(Native method)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.example.hellojni.HelloView.draw(HelloView.java:80)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.example.hellojni.HelloView.run(HelloView.java:48)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-23 13:22:44.869 24629-24889/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] 
07-23 13:22:44.899 24629-248
```

When I debugged the error was on this line:

```
env-> CallVoidMethod(getcanvasClass, drawBitmapFunction, jniBitmap->_storedBitmapPixels, width - jniBitmap->_bitmapInfo.width/2,
                                                 height - jniBitmap->_bitmapInfo.height/2, paint);
```

But I don't know why, as the same code pattern using "android/graphics/Bitmap" and call createBitmap methods works fine.

Thank you in advanced for help.

I change the code like this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_hellojni_JniBitmapHolder_drawingBitmap(JNIEnv *env, jfloat width, jfloat height, jobject canvas, jobject paint) {

    // TODO
    jclass getcanvasClass = env-> GetObjectClass(canvas);
    jmethodID drawBitmapFunction = env -> GetMethodID(getcanvasClass, "drawBitmap", "(Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;FFLandroid/graphics/Paint;)V");


    env -> CallVoidMethod(canvas, drawBitmapFunction, jniBitmap->_storedBitmapPixels, width - jniBitmap->_bitmapInfo.width/2,
                         height - jniBitmap->_bitmapInfo.height/2, paint);


}
```

log:

```
07-23 21:44:41.539 17369-17369/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, float, float, android.graphics.Paint) on instance of java.lang.Class<android.graphics.Canvas>
07-23 21:44:41.539 17369-17369/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     in call to CallVoidMethodV
07-23 21:44:41.539 17369-17369/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     from void com.example.hellojni.JniBitmapHolder.drawingBitmap(float, float, android.graphics.Canvas, android.graphics.Paint)
07-23 21:44:41.539 17369-17369/com.example.hellojni A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
```

Still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of **android.graphics.Canvas** to execute a call to **drawBitmap()**. This method is not a static method, so it expects an object, not an object's "class".

The confusing part is that in Java, class of an object is an object of type `java.lang.CLass<>`. In your case, **getcanvasClass** variable is of type `java.lang.Class<android.graphics.Canvas>`. You can always go from an object to class object (e.g. `env->GetObjectClass(object)`), but usually you cannot find an object if you only know which class it belongs to.

The bottom line is that your method needs an actual canvas object to draw the bitmap. You can probably obtain such object in Java, and pass it to the native method.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but the error still persist. Could you help with some example code sir ? Thanks

Comment: your C++ code looks OK now. What could go wrong? Most likely, your apk still use the old library. Add some log statement to verify this. Less likely, the  Java side that calls `JniBitmapHolder.drawingBitmap()` is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

drawBitmap() is not a static function, so we should call by a obj not a clazz, like this:`env->CallVoidMethod(canvas, "drawBitmap", "(Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;FFLandroid/graphics/Paint;)V")`

Comment: Other than your weird spelling of 'class', I don't see what this answer adds that isn't already in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38542456/10871073), posted over seven years ago.